# Display tables from a DB linked Database in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

I have a normal Oracle schema where I can see all the tables and if you click on one, it pops up a new tab with the contents in it, perfect.

I also have a Database that is connected via DbLink, and I can see all the tables when I execute a query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES@TARGET_DB;
```

However, I would like this list from the above query to show up similarly how tables are displayed under the schema of a normal database.  Is this possible with SQL Developer ?

Comment: `dblink` is to query a different database from one database. wrt `SQL Developer`, you can connect to the remote database directly! And I dont think what you look for is possible!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking at the `connections` panel and viewing a specific schema associated with your login. Certainly, if you click on your database link schema object(s), one will not have a nice display of objects in the schema associated with the database link.

Comment: Patrick - that is correct, however i do not see the schema for the linked database.  ideally if it were in that dropdown, that is exactly what i would be looking for.  can you confirm if its possible to see that?

Answer (score 0):

By "pop up", if you are talking about "completion insight" property of the SQL developer code editor, I am pretty sure the vanilla SQL developer doesn't provide the completion insight for remote tables queried using dblinks (Not atleast the version 3).

I don't think the devs would bother to add this feature, as it would simply make the code editor work more and give a sluggish end user experience for the developer. Think about all the extra parsing work and network delays before the code completion popup appears.

Update based on your comment:
It looks like you want to add a new connection. To add a new connection,

1. Right click on the "Connections" in the left pane and select "New
   Connection"
2. Fill in the DB details (credentials, hostname,port,etc.,) in the
   resulting form

PS: This should belong in superuser.

Comment: nope, i just want to see a list of all the tables as if the dbLinked DB Schema is in the database connected schema drop down on the left.

Comment: this is just outlining how to create a new connection.  i have a connection to a database, and from that database there is a dbLink to another DB.  i cannot connect directly to the dbLinked database.  however i can see its tables using the intial above query.

Comment: @user1772250: If you want to see the tables in the left pane for "dblinked" database as your currently connected database, you have to create a new connection to the dblinked database. A connection is what enables you to view the tables of the currently logged in database in the first place.

Comment: i dont have direct access to the DBLinekd Database, so i cannot create a connection to it.  looks like this is impossible.